# How to get dom objects in dijit ContentPane content

Tags: dojo

There is one image in dojo/dijit's content. I want to set click event for the image but it can't catch the event.

[the code in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gisfinder/v2mu8h73/)

```
    <script>dojoConfig = {parseOnLoad: true}</script>
    <script src='../../_static/js/dojo/dojo.js'></script>

    <script>
require(["dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dojo/domReady!"], function(ContentPane){
    new ContentPane({
      content:"<p><img src='https://ss0.bdstatic.com/5aV1bjqh_Q23odCf/static/superman/img/logo/logo_white_fe6da1ec.png' onclick='clickHandler()' /></p>",
      style:"height:125px"
    }, "targetID").startup();

function clickHandler()
{
alert("img clicked");
}
});
    </script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
    <div id="targetID">
    I get replaced.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited.

```js
require([
  'dojo/dom-construct',  
  'dijit/layout/ContentPane',
  'dojo/domReady!'
], function(domConstruct, ContentPane){
  new ContentPane({
    content: '<div id="imageDiv"></div>',
    style: 'height:125px'
  }, 'targetID').startup();
  domConstruct.create('img', {
    src: 'https://ss0.bdstatic.com/5aV1bjqh_Q23odCf/static/superman/img/logo/logo_white_fe6da1ec.png',
    onclick: function(){ alert('i have been clicked') }
  }, 'imageDiv');
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<div id="targetID">I get replaced.</div>
```

Comment: In ContentPane, there are anchor object and image objects. So I expect to catch anchor click event and image click event.

Comment: I have edited code so that the alert is now attached to the image.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the clickHandler function within the require function. This means that it will not be available after require returns. At the console you can see an error when the image is clicked: "clickHandler is not defined". You can easily solve this by defining the clickHandler function outside of require().

```
<script>
require(["dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dojo/domReady!"], function(ContentPane){
    new ContentPane({
      content:"<p><img src='https://ss0.bdstatic.com/5aV1bjqh_Q23odCf/static/superman/img/logo/logo_white_fe6da1ec.png' onclick='clickHandler()' /></p>",
      style:"height:125px"
    }, "targetID").startup();

});
function clickHandler()
{
alert("img clicked");
}
</script>
```